# Have to click multiple times to drag window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am running Windows 10 Pro, and notice that when I try to drag and move an explorer (or settings etc) window (i.e My Documents), I have to click 3 or 4 times before it actually moves - otherwise, I click and hold, but it doesn't move anywhere.

No idea what is causing this - thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be two-fold. Firstly, for some reason which I do not know, the region to the right of the menu bar (marked X in the figure below) is relatively unresponsive to clicks or double-clicks. You have to use the region at the top near the edge of the window (checked in blue). **This is the most likely problem**.

[image]

Secondly, double-clicking an explorer window may maximize the window or lock it for dragging if the double-clicking is done simultaneaously with movement. If the double-click speed of your mouse is set to high and you double-click the explorer window at a lower speed without movement, the window will neither maximize nor move i.e., *the window will appear to apparently be unresponsive to your clicking*. You need to adjust the double-click speed of your mouse and remember to lock and drag at the same time if you want to move the window.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how much of an idiot you made me feel lol. Your 'red X marks the spot' image proved correct - thank you so much - I was ripping my hair out!

Comment: That's an annoying feature, they should delineate the two somehow

Answer (score 0):

When in dual(or more) screen mode you need to double click on the task bar on the window you want to move...once... to wake it up, then again and hold the second click to move screen. 
Explained a different way...lets say your working on the main screen and you have both screens up with something on both. When you click on and or are working on the main screen the second screen is "de-selected" and the task pane on top may gray out. To move that screen you need to click the task bar once to wake it up then again while holding the second click. Make sense?